# Website Review CMS (similar in nature to Forexpeacearmy.com)

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script, website-review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

I was wondering if anyone know of any CMSs that are similar to Forexpeacearmy.com ie Different categories with lists of websites in them. The ability for users to review websites.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) with the [GD Star Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/screenshots/) plugin. You may have to make a post for each website you list, or create a new post type (or use a [template](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress/)).

There is a [good O'Reilly book on the subject](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059615979X) of rating systems if you want to tweak the algorithms.